# How to avoid redundant container linking in Docker when propagating IP addresses?

Tags: docker

Let's assume I have a server running Docker. In order to create a simple load-balanced system, I run two instances of an application in seperate containers. Both of them communicate with the database which resides in a separate container as well. In order to access the database, I need to make its IP address (which changes every time I kill the container because I rebuild it for example) available through container linking. The links provide the IP of the database via environment variables.

In total there are three containers. Two of them need to know the IP address of the third (via an environment variable), but I have to create two container links and name two links for the same IP address.

```
$ docker run -d --name dbcontainer company/database:1.1
$ docker run -d --name appinstance0 company/app:2.1 --link dbcontainer:dblink0
$ docker run -d --name appinstance1 company/app:2.1 --link dbcontainer:dblink1
```

`appinstance0` can now use `DBLINK0_PORT_1234_TCP_ADDR` and `appinstance1` can use `DBLINK1_PORT_1234_TCP_ADDR` to know the IP address of the database container.

Both variables contain the exact same information. So if I decided to add another instance, I would have to create a `dblink2` and so on... That is far away from being practical. Is there a different way to reference an IP address of a container? I'd like to have only one variable which contains the IP address of the database container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a different way to reference an IP address of a container?

Yes, [docker links also define hostnames](http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/#updating-the-etchosts-file). So you have the option of not using environment variables to get the database IP address.

You can start your containers as follow:

```
$ docker run -d --name dbcontainer company/database:1.1
$ docker run -d --name appinstance0 company/app:2.1 --link dbcontainer:dblink
$ docker run -d --name appinstance1 company/app:2.1 --link dbcontainer:dblink
```

provided that your app config file set the mysql host to `dblink`.

There are other ways to discover your database IP address but without docker, so you would have to learn how to use another tool for that task. If you want to learn more, search for "service discovery and docker".

Comment: Thanks! So the Docker documentation is misleading as it talks of the links as creating link containers and two containers can not have the same name.

Comment: I have not found it misleading, what sentence in the doc got you confused?

Comment: It's correct that two containers cannot have the same name. However for '--link <containerName>:<alias>', the <alias> is referenced internally to the container created. Therefore in Thomas example, you could have two containers '--name appinstance0' and '--name appinstance1', both link to dbcontainer.

Comment: @Thomasleveil I think must have been "You've learned that a link creates a source container that can provide information about itself to a recipient container." in https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/ Anyways, in my head I was convinced that a link is a container itself and thus must have a unique name.